# The exponential map at $m$ and constant velocity

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be a geodesically complete manifold and $m\in M$. The exponential map at $m$ is 
$$
       \exp_m: T_mM\rightarrow M \\
        v \mapsto \gamma(1)
$$
where $\gamma$ is the geodesic $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow M$ such that $\gamma(0)=m$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0)=v$.

Now, I read that
$$
       \int_0^1 \parallel \dot{\gamma}(t) \parallel dt =  \int_0^1 \parallel v \parallel dt = \parallel v \,\,\parallel
$$

I do not know why $\dot{\gamma}(t)=v$ for all $t$. It seems that I am missing something quite fundamental here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is not that $\dot{\gamma}(t) = v$ for all $t$; it's that these two vectors have the same length.

The reason for this equality is that geodesics are constant-speed curves, for otherwise they'd have acceleration in the tangential direction, which is one of the key things that the definition disallows. And since $\|\dot{\gamma}(0) \| = \| v\|$, we get that 
$\| \dot{\gamma}(t) \| = \| v\|$ for all $t$.

Comment: Ok. The definition is still just the solution of a system of differential equations, for me.

Comment: You might want to check out the Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) to see why (a paragraph after equation 1) the differential equation you've got is equivalent to the statement that the covariant derivative of the tangent, in the tangent direction, is zero. If your introduction to geodesics comes in the form of "they are solutions to this (unmotivated) set of differential equations," I'd seriously recommend finding a new book or a new teacher. :)